# Mongodb aggregate and unwind behaviour - duplication

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am currently using the following query to unwind and 'join' several collections:

```
    User.aggregate([{
                "$match": {
                    "verified": true,
                    "active_account": true
                }
            },
            {
                "$lookup": {
                    "from": "screens",
                    "localField": "_id",
                    "foreignField": "user_obj",
                    "as": "screenings"
                }
            },
            {
                "$unwind": "$screens"
            },
            {
                "$lookup": {
                    "from": "drinks",
                    "localField": "_id",
                    "foreignField": "user_id",
                    "as": "drinks"
                }
            },
            {
                "$unwind": "$drinks"
            },
            {
                "$group": {
                    "_id": "$_id",
                    "smsmobile": {
                        "$first": "$smsmobile"
                    },
                    "screens": {
                        "$push": "$screens"
                    },
                    "drinks": {
                        "$push": "$drinks"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]...
```

The issue I am currently experiences is that for both drinks and screens they each have records which are duplicated - however in the actual database they are single item. For example, screens in the database only has two records, but in the above process four are outputted.

It would appear that the aggregate unwind process is generating these duplicates. I welcome any thoughts on this.

Sample output for screen is below. Take note of the _id, there is no duplicate sin the collection it self.

```
[ { _id: 58e901837a085502ec6b4b6b,
    updatedAt: 2017-04-08T15:28:03.153Z,
    createdAt: 2017-04-08T15:28:03.153Z,
    user_obj: 58e901267a085502ec6b4b69,
    screen: 1,
    difficult_sit: 1,
    group: 2,
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 58e901837a085502ec6b4b6b,
    updatedAt: 2017-04-08T15:28:03.153Z,
    createdAt: 2017-04-08T15:28:03.153Z,
    user_obj: 58e901267a085502ec6b4b69,
    screen: 1,
    difficult_sit: 1,
    group: 2,
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 58eb4001ee18b403f05a9043,
    updatedAt: 2017-04-10T08:19:13.857Z,
    createdAt: 2017-04-10T08:19:13.857Z,
    user_obj: 58e901267a085502ec6b4b69,
    screen: 1,
    difficult_sit: null,
    group: 2,
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 58eb4001ee18b403f05a9043,
    updatedAt: 2017-04-10T08:19:13.857Z,
    createdAt: 2017-04-10T08:19:13.857Z,
    user_obj: 58e901267a085502ec6b4b69,
    screen: 1,
    difficult_sit: null,
    group: 2,
    __v: 0 } ]
```

Comment: it's because of the $lookup. I guess you have several documents in `drinks` or `screens` that have the same user_id or user_obj

Comment: That is correct. I have multiple items for each user within each collection. I thought that lookup can handle this?

Comment: What do you mean handle this? Mongodb can't choose which document to keep if there is duplicate, so it returns everything

Comment: There are no duplicates in the database itself. It is the process which is creating the duplicates.

Comment: I have updated the question with an example of the output.

Comment: Use `"screens": {
                        "$addToSet": "$screens"
                    },
                    "drinks": {
                        "$addToSet": "$drinks"
                    }` in the `$group` stage or Try moving the `{
                "$unwind": "$screens"
            },` after second `$lookup` stage.